# Jquery tablesorter not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tablesorter

I am new to `Jquery` and web-programming in general. I am trying to use the `tablesorter` `jquery` plugin, for one of  my programs only to find that it is not working. After some tweaking, I was unable to make it work. So resorted to Stack Overflow.

Can you please explain what my mistake is? Thanks in advance :)

Now, my `html` file(following code) is in the same folder as my "jquery.tablesorter.js" is in. I'm trying to use google Jquery CDN from the W3 schools quoted below :

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_install.asp

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
         $("#myTable").tablesorter( {sortList: [[0,0], [1,0]]} ); 
    } 
); 
</script>
</head>
<body>  
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
    <th>Last Name</th> 
    <th>First Name</th> 
    <th>Email</th> 
    <th>Due</th> 
    <th>Web Site</th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 
<tr> 
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>John</td> 
    <td>jsmith@gmail.com</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Bach</td> 
    <td>Frank</td> 
    <td>fbach@yahoo.com</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.frank.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Doe</td> 
    <td>Jason</td> 
    <td>jdoe@hotmail.com</td> 
    <td>$100.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.jdoe.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Conway</td> 
    <td>Tim</td> 
    <td>tconway@earthlink.net</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.timconway.com</td> 
</tr> 
</tbody> 
</table> 
</body>
</html>

for filename in os.listdir (input_dir) :
  f = open(file_name, 'rb')
  file_content = f.readlines()
  f.close()
  len_file = len(file_content)
  while( i < len_file ):
    line = file_content[i].split(delimiter)
    i +=1
```

**Update1:** I'm able to fix this error. Seems adding Content Distribution from Google caused the error changing it to a internal directory seems to solve the problem.

Actually, I changed,

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to this line.

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

and it worked :)

Any ideas why Google CDN didn't work ? Thanks! :)

**Update2:**

When you test the code locally, try to add ***http:*** before the google CDN call.ie,

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Enjoy the plugin:)

Comment: Please expand upon your original question. It is *really* hard to understand what you want from your question.

Comment: It looks right, what is not working?  Have you tried to remove the sortList information and see if it will work?

Comment: @xxmbabanexx : I have some more info on google CDN. But seems like the error is due to that line. Let me know if you need more info. Thanks !

Comment: I think the problem you're running into is that URLs that start with `//` don't work locally. So if you want to test your code locally, you'll need to add `http:` in front.

Comment: Spot on :) Thanks a lot @Mottie. Edited my question to add answer for future references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet it is working, you're just not seeing any table styling because the `tablesorter.css` file isn't loaded. Try clicking on the table head and see if it sorts.

Comment: Seems Google CDN is the culprit,Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

You can try - It works for me..

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 

         $("#myTable").tablesorter({sortList:[[0,0],[2,1]], widgets:'zebra']});
    } 
);
```